# How to type a React.ComponentType with a static property?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flowtype, next.js

I'm writing a HOC component for next.js pages, and this HOC needs to accept a component with a specific `getInitialProps` static function.

I can't get figure out the right typing for this with flow:

```
const wrapComponent = (Component: React.ComponentType<*>) => {
    const original: Function = Component.getInitialProps;

    return class extends React.Component<*> {
        static async getInitialProps(ctx) {
            const props = await original(ctx);
            return {
                ...props,
                custom: 'a',
            };
        }

        render() {
            return <Component {...this.props} />;
        }
    }
}
```

I get this error:

```
5:     const original: Function = Component.getInitialProps;
                                            ^ property `getInitialProps`. Property not found in
5:     const original: Function = Component.getInitialProps;
                                  ^ statics of React$Component
```

**[Demo](https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoAlgWwA5wE4AuyYAhgM5gBKApiQMZFR5yZgDketDbA3KqnTgA7MkQR4S2AMItcQ6kKIBeMAAoZOYQoIAuKlwIA6DXO0AVAJ7ZqAHhAA+AJRgl9sAG9UYb2EEii+OgA5uhCJDB6AGIArkIM6MIuYCZaioZB1AQAkkLoBOjhAArM2GR8Xj6cBNF4Qr4w5BTUAB4ECgAmFDT0RinyinZunj4jYKIk+XSkZBZxYBnZuflFJWSqDM3Ow6M7fqJg2KtJJAgkeWCBIWEw6wSbfDs7VTV124+Php+HcKUANBXvXbRUQsPRsEhsf6AnwAXwejxh-HenCE7WoeFUWwBgOetTANj62g8n0MBAAFugyIZvqUYWBgPZ4TtESNEYigA)**

Comment: React components never had an `getInitialProps` method. If those are specific components then you have to type `Component` as such, not as `React.Component`.

Comment: @FelixKling you mean create a class interface?

Comment: That would work I guess.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
// @flow

import React from 'react';
import type {ComponentType} from 'react';

interface StaticInterface {
  fn(): void;
}

class NoStatic extends React.Component<{}> { 
}

class WithStatic extends React.Component<{}> {
  static fn() {}
}

const c1: ComponentType<{}> = NoStatic;                       
const c2: ComponentType<{}> = WithStatic;                     
const c3: ComponentType<{}> & StaticInterface = WithStatic;   
// const c4: ComponentType<{}> & StaticInterface = NoStatic;     // NOT OK
```

[(demo)](https://flow.org/try/#0PTAEAEDMBsHsHcBQiCWBbADrATgF1AEoCmAhgMb6TaxqgDk2pFdA3KpjvrgJ4ZGgBvAMI0sAOyJjcAFV5EAvqCo16jcrlbIUUotkjl+AZVwlcKMgEkdeg4MSglYgBQBKAFygAbrBQATNvLIZNAkAM6hoABysMam5qBEAB64kr4RxOoAdCIcElIAPALyAHyCoIiBiMFhEQDqKLgAFrFmZAnJqelMuNmisHm4hSV2DqEmrY6ugoGVZP1joGQAjB454pIyckOlALxRMePmLA4np2fnJ1Xz+GQATKt9A7J826B79U0tRxc-51diCzIAGYHrkNs8iK8AGSgL6Waz6Mj8d4NZqHMjHByIECLa6LAAsoPWUgh0Nh6KsKRsSLe+zhmJOOMiAHlpKBmQBpIA)

I find this pretty confusing myself. I adapted it from this:

https://blog.bluematador.com/posts/enforcing-method-presence-in-react-components-with-flow

Related:

https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/2048

https://github.com/facebook/flow/pull/3994

Comment: Oh yes, totally what I was looking for! Thanks a lot :)